# How to add extra parameters to a custom log format in Winston?

Tags: node.js, winston

When you console.log you can add extra params as:

```
console.log("The message", { foo: 123 });
```

And that will print the message plus a serialized version of the second param (and any other param). Im creating a custom log format using Winston like this:

```
const winston = require('winston');

const logFormat = winston.format.printf(({ level, message, timestamp }) => {
    return `${timestamp} ${level}: ${message}`;
  });

  const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: winston.format.combine(winston.format.timestamp(), logFormat),
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.File({ filename: './logs/error.log', level: 'error' }),
      new winston.transports.File({ filename: './logs/combined.log' })
    ]
  });
```

This tho will ignore any extra params when doing `logger.info("This gets in the logs", { this: "not" });`

How can a similar behavior to console.log can be achieved with Winston?

Answer (score 0):

You can JSON.stringify the whole thing and put it in the logger or  use + (performs concatination) instead of a , (doesnt do that)

```
logger.info("This gets in the logs"+ JSON.stringify({ this: "not" }));
```

Hope this helps